# C, logs, binary, and the number four. they don't mix

Tags: c, binary, int, long-integer, unsigned

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/* converts to binary using logs */
int main()
{
    long int decimalNUM = 0, binaryNUM = 0, exponentNUM = 0;
    printf("Enter a number to be converted to binary.\t");
    scanf("%ld", &decimalNUM);
    fflush(stdin);
    int origDEC = decimalNUM;
       while (decimalNUM > 0)
       {
          exponentNUM = (log(decimalNUM))/(log(2));
          binaryNUM += pow(10, exponentNUM);
          decimalNUM -= pow(2, exponentNUM);
       }
       printf("\nBINARY FORM OF %ld is %ld", origDEC, binaryNUM);
    getchar();
    return binaryNUM;
}
```

If STDIN is 4 it returns 99 and it should not. On IDEONE it returns 100. Why?

EDIT seems that any even number above two returns something with nines in it

Comment: Why exactly would you use logs for this? You *already have* the number in binary.

Comment: Have you considered using bitwise operators instead of floating-point math routines? You do realize that floating-point is subject to rounding errors, which might explain why you're getting 99 instead of 100?

Comment: @tekknolagi: Computers work with bits. A number is stored in a computer's memory as a pattern of bits - literally in binary. Are you just wondering how to print that out?

Comment: can someone define bitwise operators? and yes please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point operations like log are not exact.  On my machine this code runs as expected (4 on STDIN gives 100).

One way you could do this, is by using the mod (%) operator with successive powers of two.

Comment: Can I have some help with that?

Comment: start with the highest power of two i think it's (ULONG_MAX/2+1)

Comment: if your input is higher than that, print a 1, otherwise print a 0.  Then, set your input to the modulus (% operator) of the input with the highest power of two.  Repeat.

Comment: There are many ways to go about this.  You could use subtraction instead of the mod operator.

Comment: But you would only subtract if you printed a 1.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine : http://ideone.com/PPZG5

As mentioned in the comments, your approach is really strange.

A general base-n conversion routine looks like:

```
void print_base_n(int val, int n) {
    if(val==0) { printf("0"); return; }
    else if(val < n) { printf("%d", val); return; }
    print_base_n(val/n, n);
    printf("%d", val % n);
}
```

Comment: it should say `else if(val < n)`.  If you wrote `else if (val <= n)` then you would see 20